# Print unrecognized escapes ('\*') in R

Tags: r

In R (3.2.2):

```
print('\*') #triggers an error
print('\\*') #prints '\\*'     (two backslashes)
```

How do I print '\*' (1 backslash)? I've read FAQ 7.3.7 and various answers here about printing literal backslashes, but they all seem to say 'use two backslashes', which doesn't work.

In case it matters, what I really want to do is

```
str <- sprintf("complex string \* %s %s %s",other,complex,strings),
```

so I can't use

```
cat('\\*') which does produce '\*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after `message` or `cat`, which prints to the screen

```
R> message("\\*")
\*
R> cat('\\*')
\*
```

The print function returns an object (note the `[1]`)

```
R> print('\\*')
[1] "\\*"
```

which you can then pass. So

```
## Doesn't work
R> m1 = message("\\*")
\*
R> m1
NULL

## Good to go
R> m2 = print('\\*')
[1] "\\*"
R> m2
[1] "\\*"
```

Hence to use with `sprintf`, we have

```
str <- sprintf("complex string \\* %s","test") 
message(str)
```

Comment: I'd never encountered 'message' before, so thanks for that, but it won't do  for the same reason cat won't - I don't want to print to the screen - needs to work with sprintf.

Comment: See my updated answer. The key is to remember that print returns an object. `message` formats that object.

Comment: So what I actually need to do is to construct a string object that, when printed, will appear as: `> whatever \\* whatever' in the expectation that when used (by `cat` or `system`) this will be converted to `\*`. This works for me, thanks.